# Get the list of groovy scripts currently executing

Tags: linux, groovy

I have a requirement to get the list of groovy scripts currently executing on a linux machine, based on which I need to decide if another groovy script should execute or it should error out.

The problem is the classpath being set on the machine is a very long one, so when try to do execute a `ps -ef` from my code I do not get the full path, but I only get the truncated command (I read in other questions that linux has a 4k limit) used to launch.

Since groovy scrips execute on a JVM I also tried the `jps` command but I only get the class name like `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter` and a few parameters passed to it, but not the script name.

Any ideas how to get the list of groovy scripts currently executing in my code?

Comment: Have you tried `ps -auxww`

Comment: Yes, I have tried, it does not work, as i mentioned the kernel itself has a limit of around 4k on the buffer so i'm getting the truncated value, it is not the terminal limitation. adding `ww` will only increase the limitations on the terminal display.

Comment: Have you tried `jps -v`?

Comment: yes, i have tried, as mentioned I only get the class name like `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter` and a few parameters passed to it, but not the script name.

Comment: Have you tried `jps -mlvV`?

Comment: Just tried, getting truncated output there as well

Comment: Man, sure would be nice to be able to specify a file containing the classpath, rather than having it chunk up the command line.  Is it possible to use the CLASSPATH env variable when starting your scripts?  Would this result in a smaller result from ps/jps?

Comment: @billjamesdev We are using the CLASSPATH env variable and appending our required libraries on the classpath, but the problem is that it gets resolved to the full path while application is invoked.

Comment: @ManishKothari One more Q.. is CLASSPATH expanded on your command line because your script said something like "java -cp %CLASSPATH% ..."?   If not, then I'm stumped.  If so, then you should be able to remove the "-cp %CLASSPATH%", as java should just find that env variable.

Comment: @billjamesdev  the problem is that i cannot change it in the production system now. I have to find some other way to list down the processes.